# No overload for method 'Create' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#

Part of my code sends a file from the disk to a server using ftp. I want to be able to specify a string instead of a static filename but not sure how :(

```
string test = "string";
FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.0.29", test);
```

Comment: Instead of `(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.0.29", test);` , `(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.0.29" + test);` ? This is just a strings question it seems?

Comment: What do you expect passing `test` in your example to do?

Comment: What i wanted was to generate a random string and save that as a filename, I actually managed to do this in the end.

Comment: static class RandomUtil
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Get random string of 11 characters.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>Random string.</returns>
            public static string GetRandomString()
            {
                string path = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                path = path.Replace(".txt", ""); // Remove period.
                return path;
            }
        }

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, i'm relatively new to c#, transitioning from python to c# :p

Answer (score 0):

The [Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `WebRequest` class accepts only one parameter, either a string or an Uri. But you are passing two here, I think it should be something like this:

```
string test = "string";
FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.0.29/" + test);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create FtpWebRequest, you first specify the URL, then when you get the object, you send the file. See the following.

```
string url = "ftp://192.168.0.29";
string filename = "C:\\file.txt";
FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

using (var ftpstream = ftpReq.GetRequestStream())
using (var filestream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    filestream.CopyTo(ftpstream, 1000);
}
```